# Internet Slow after Disconnecting VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. For the past few weeks, I am facing this weird issue.

I am using VPN Unlimited native Ubuntu app to connect to VPN. After disconnecting VPN Internet becomes slow, takes much time to load a website. I suspect it is some DNS related issue. I can reboot to fix it.

I found some change in the **/etc/resolv.conf** file. After VPN disconnection the contents of file,

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.200.0.1
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

After rebooting the contents of file,

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Not sure whether the slow Internet is due to the additional nameserver in the file which automatically gets added by VPN. Can anyone help to fix this ?

Comment: I don't know that particular VPN software but it seems that it edits the `/etc/resolv.conf` to point you to a DNS server in their network, but "forgets" to undo the changes when it exits. Slow speed is due to every request first trying to resolve address using the host on `10.×` and only uses the internal daemon upon timeout.

Comment: This is the issue. I have informed the devs and they have fixed it. Now the nameserver 10.x is properly removed after disconnecting VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a few times in residential broadbands.

In some cases, it was the ISPs throttling some types of traffic and it escaped the throttling mechanism when using a VPN. Detecting it or proving it is really hard.

It also can be that the nameserver used by your VPN is a lot faster than the nameservers used when not connected to said VPN. This one is easy to spot, it makes downloads slow to start but does not prevent them to reach normal speed. It usually makes browsing miserable as it requires lots of small downloads.